# Result as a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I wrote a code that gives you a few numbers out if you enter a number

```
n= int(input("Enter the beginning number: "))
i=0
print(n)
while n > 1:
    if n%2 == 0:         
       n = n/2
       print(n)
    else:
       n = 3*n+1
       print(n)
       i += 1;
```

but now how can I add it to look like [..,..,..,..]

I already try it with adding

```
theList = []
....
.... 
....
if..
...
   theList.append(i) # or theList.append(n) its the same
```

so how could that work

Comment: you alerady tried appending to a list, but what happened? That's the right idea, but we don't know what didn't work for you

Comment: the results I get is 1 2 3 4 5 one below the other not like [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: maybe instead of all the `....`, you can show the *actual* code that attempted to append to `theList`?

Comment: good luck with Collatz conjecture  :-)

Comment: its the same like above

Answer (score 4):

append the numbers to your list then when you want to view it print out your list like this:

```
print ','.join(map(str,theList)) #thanks to adam smith for catching that
```

it makes a list like this:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

print like this:

```
'a,b,c,d'
```

Comment: This will raise a `TypeError` since OP is casting input to an integer.

Comment: you need to do `print ','.join(map(str,theList))` then it will work :)

Comment: I get five empty rows if I enter 10 ?